# Python - IEEE754 32bit to Microchip 32bit converter

Tags: rotation, shift

This is my first question on this site.
I need to convert Microchip 32bit hex number to IEEE754 32bit hex number.
Difference between those two formats:

```
Microchip = exponent + sign + fraction

IEEE 754 = sign + exponent + fraction
```

To convert between the formats circular shift rotation of the top 9 bits should be done. 
The question is how to do it in Python(2.7)?

Example:

```
0x833C0000 -> 0b10000011 00111100 00000000 00000000  Microchip 32bit, 

0x41BC0000 -> 0b01000001 10111100 00000000 00000000  IEEE754 32bit
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is straightforward and is printed below:

```
def formatHex( val ):
   return format( val, '#04x' )

def microchip32_2_ieee754( m32 ):
   sign = (1 << 31) if m32 & (1 << 23) else 0
   expoent = ( m32 & 0xFF000000 ) >>  1
   return  expoent + sign + (m32 & 0x007FFFFF)

def ieee754_2_microchip32( ieee ):
   sign = (1 << 23) if ieee & (1 << 31) else 0
   expoent = ( ieee & 0x7F800000 ) <<  1
   return  expoent + sign + (ieee & 0x007FFFFF)

if __name__ == "__main__":

   m32 = 0x833C0000;

   print "Microchip 32: ", formatHex( m32 )
   print "IEEE 754: ", formatHex( microchip32_2_ieee754( m32 ) )
   print "Microchip 32: ", formatHex(
                              ieee754_2_microchip32(
                                 microchip32_2_ieee754( m32 ) ) )
```